# Table width are different in Outlook then on web browser

Tags: css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I have problem with creating table to create mail with order confirmation.

First row in table are not equal with the next one. On web browser everything is fine with width. I've tried everything and nothing worked. Lines in html:

```html
<td style=\"color: #999999; word-break:break-all; width: 275px;\">
```

I have tried also something like this:

```html
<td width=\"100%\" style=\"color: #999999;\">
```

As for the next line and all subsequent tables everything are displayed correctly.

Please help me because I don't have idea what to do.

Comment: Are you able to post more of your code? It may be something else wrapping around your cells that is throwing these off

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Yes, thank You very much for your answer but as I can see element 
 
td style and td width are supported in Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank You very much for your answer but as I can see element

```html
td style
```

and

```html
td width
```

are supported in outlook.